# SQL Query that requires an age above 25

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table

**Patient**:

```
PatientNo {PK}
fName
lName
Address
phoneNo
DOB
```

Here is the question

Get the names of patients aged above 25 whose location is in 'Letterkenny'

Below is my solution

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, address, DOB
FROM Patient
WHERE DOB BETWEEN #01/01/1900# AND #31/12/1991#
  AND address = 'Letterkenny';
```

Is my solution correct?

Also is there another way to do the age is it possible to do this instead for the age.

```
WHERE DOB > 25
```

Comment: you need to convert date to age, usually you need to subtract DOB from today's date to get number of days/month/years and this will be the age you can compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate the age by subtracting birth of date from current date:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, address, DOB
FROM Patient    
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), DOB)/365 > 25
AND address=’Letterkenny’;
```

while NOW() returns the current date in mySql.

Comment: so i just change the where to your code and that is the answer? So this will return patients who are over 25?

Comment: That depends on the database engine you are using. Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, or mySql?

Comment: @MarkDoherty Of course add `AND address=’Letterkenny’`

Comment: i'm not familiar with the way you did it.

Comment: mySQL is the engine i would use

Comment: In MySQL replace GETDATE() with NOW()

Comment: would where DOB >25 work or is that an illegal expression?

Comment: I changed the query to use mySql engine.

Comment: you can't compare date with integer. Apples and Oranges.

Comment: so what would this do would it run or would it give an error?

Comment: WHERE DOB BETWEEN #01/01/1900# AND #31/12/1991#

Comment: Did you try my updated query above? What error does it give you?

Comment: For your error, try this instead: WHERE DOB BETWEEN '01/01/1900' AND '31/12/1991', but this is not the correct way like I mentioned before.

Comment: i don't have access to mysql on my laptop i only have access to it at university. thanks for your help. very much appreciated.